# Scraping Ajax using Python

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt4, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to get the data in the table at this website which is updated via jquery after the page loads (I have permission) :

http://whichchart.com/

I currently use selenium and beautifulsoup to get data, however because this data is not visible in the html source, I can't access it. I have tried PyQt4 but it likewise does not get the updated html source.

The values are visible in firebug and chrome developer, so are there any python packages out there which can exploit this and feed it to beautifulsoup?

I'm not a massive techie so ideally I would like a solution which would work in Python or the next easiest software type.

I'm aware I can get it via proprietary "screen-scraper" software, but that is expensive.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that it is the right tool but I can get the updated source via `QWebView` after `loadFinished` is emitted. What did you try with PyQt4?

Comment: Thanks Avaris. I used the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356948/scraping-javascript-driven-web-pages-with-pyqt4-how-to-access-pages-that-need . You say QwebView would get the updated source? What code do I put in?

Comment: Well, that code does get the updated source for me too.

Comment: Really? The code in the OP, replacing sitescraper.net with whichchart.com, gives the values in the returned html? Hmmmm, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. One possibility would be Javascript is disabled in `QtWebKit` settings. But if you are not disabling it explicitly, it is enabled by default. Unless you are using a custom PyQt/Qt that you built yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page is making AJAX call to get a data to http://whichchart.com/service.php?action=NewcastleCoal which returns values in JSON. So you can do the following:

- Use urllib to get data using HTTP
- Parse that data with json library reads method
- Now you have a python object to process

If you need to process HTML page content I would suggest to use library like BeautifulSoup or [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Thanks Maksym. You're right that that works. However I would like a more mechanical approach as I have a fair few websites to get data from so my preferred method is to use the updated source.

Comment: @user578582 Makysm's response is the mechanical approach, Parsing HTML is a pain and very difficult to maintain, it is very good that you have this data avaialable to you in json.

Comment: @dm03514 Ideally you should use API, if not available try using AJAX JSON. HTML parsing is a last resort if no any other option is available to you. JSON might be also be pain to maintain, if it changes with site updates (it is not official API interface after all)