# Issue with PyQt4, while trying to authenticate and connect to SharePoint

Tags: python, python-2.7, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I will write in steps what i want to do. It would be better to understand while english isnt my native language.

1. Authenticate to SharePoint
2. Go to http://cdc-rnd-sps34.dev.local/Lists/SC_Incidents/Open.aspx
3. Execute JavaScript
4. Get HTML with executed JavaScript

Now i am getting this error:

**TypeError: 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType' object is not iterable**

I am not developer, i am QA guy and trying to do some automatizations, so i am not really good in programming. Authentication works fine in other cases where i used it. So problem in class Render that i dont understand how it fully work and i just copy-pasted it. I just dont find way how to use authenticated url adress to put it in getHtml() function.

Code:

```
import urllib2
import sys
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

user = "dev\\ani"
password = "pass"

adress = "http://cdc-rnd-sps34.dev.local/Lists/SC_Incidents/Open.aspx"

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):

        passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        passman.add_password(None, QWebPage, user, password)
        auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
        opener.addheaders = [("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")]
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)

        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

def getHtml(str_url):
    r_html = Render(str_url)
    html = r_html.frame.toHtml()

    return html

html = getHtml(adress)
print html
```

Comment: Try to use this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356948/scraping-javascript-driven-web-pages-with-pyqt4-how-to-access-pages-that-need?rq=1
hope it will help you.

Comment: Edited code by your post example. Getting HTML, BUT now authetication doesnt work...