# Scraping JavaScript WEB page requires HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, pyqt4

I'm trying to write script accessing JavaScript page secured by authentication mechanism.

When I do the following:

```
r = requests.get(url1, auth=('user', 'password'))
```

...it pass the authentication smoothly, but since the page is generated by JavaScript code it brings me the code and not the HTML content:

```
u'<SCRIPT Language=Javascript>\r\nif (window.navigator.cookieEnabled == true)\r\n{\r\nvar gmtString, d;\r\nvar vDay, vDate, vMonth, vYear, vHour;\r\nvar x = new Array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");\r\nvar y = new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");\r\nd = new Date();\r\nvDay = d.getDay();\r\nvDate = d.getDate();\r\nvMonth = d.getMonth();\r\nv
```

From other hand, I've tried to resolve this using PyQt4 like it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356948/scraping-javascript-driven-web-pages-with-pyqt4-how-to-access-pages-that-need). It should work, but this time I do not manage to pass the authentication.

Could someone point me the right direction?