# Python Web Scraping with Beautiful Soup - Having Trouble

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to try to pull either the top links or simply the top headlines from different topics on the CNN homepage. I seem to be missing something here and would appreciate some assistance. I have managed to come up with a few web scrapers before, but it's always through a lot of resistance and is quite the uphill battle.

What it looks like to me is that the links I need are ultimately stored somewhere like this:

```
<article class="cd cd--card cd--article cd--idx-1 cd--extra-small cd--has-siblings cd--media__image" data-vr-contentbox="/2015/10/02/travel/samantha-brown-travel-channel-feat/index.html" data-eq-pts="xsmall: 0, small: 300, medium: 460, large: 780, full16x9: 1100" data-eq-state="small">
```

I can grab that link after data-vr-contentbox and append it to the end of www.cnn.com and it brings me to the page I need. My problem is in actually grabbing that link. I've tried various forms to grab them. My current iteration is as follows:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.cnn.com/")

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.findAll("article"):
    test = link.get("data-vr-contentbox")
    print(test)
```

My issue here is that it only seems to grab a small number of things that I actually need. I'm only seeing two articles from politics, none from travel, etc. I would appreciate some assistance in resolving this issue. I'm looking to grab all of the links under each topic. Right now I'm just looking at politics or travel as a base to get started.

Particularly, I want to be able to specify the topic (tech, travel, politics, etc.) and grab those headlines. Whether I could simply grab the links and use those to get the headline from the respective page, or simply grab the headlines from here... I seem unable to do either. It would be nice to be able to view everything in a single topic at once, but finding out how to narrow this down isn't proving very simple.

An example article is the "IOS 9's Wi-Fi Assist feature costly" which can be found within  tags.
I want to be able to find ALL articles under, say, the Tech heading on the homepage and isolate those  tags to grab the headline. The tags for this headline look like this:

```
<div class="strip-rec-link-title ob-tcolor">IOS 9's Wi-Fi Assist feature costly</div>
```

Yet I don't know how to do BOTH of these things. I can't even seem to grab the headline, despite it being within  tags when I try this:

```
for link in soup.findAll("div"):
    print("")
    print(link)
```

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere, although I've managed to do some scrapers before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the cnn.com website has a bunch of javascript which renders a lot of the content after beautifulsoup reads it.  I opened cnn.com and looked at the source in safari and there were 197 instances of `data-vr-contentbox`.  However when I ran it through beautifulsoup and dumped it out there were only 13 instances of `data-vr-contentbox`.

There are a bunch of posts out there about handling it.  You can start with the method used in this question: [Scraping Javascript driven web pages with PyQt4 - how to access pages that need authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356948/scraping-javascript-driven-web-pages-with-pyqt4-how-to-access-pages-that-need)